# php turn unicode http link into clickable

Tags: php

i have unicode link needed to be turn into links.

Is it possible to change unicode into clickable?

Currently i'm using this piece of code to turn link into clickable

```
function clickable_link($text)
{
$ret = ' ' . $text;
$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a class=\"hrefLink\" href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a class=\"hrefLink\" href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)*[\w]+)#i", "\\1<a href=\"mailto:\\2@\\3\">\\2@\\3</a>", $ret);
$ret = substr($ret, 1);
return $ret;
}
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: can you give an example of the text that would be passed to this function?

Comment: http://www.example.com/?news=-成人话题讨论区-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah, i just added,

```
$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#isu", "\\1<a class=\"hrefLink\" href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#isu", "\\1<a class=\"hrefLink\" href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)*[\w]+)#iu", "\\1<a href=\"mailto:\\2@\\3\">\\2@\\3</a>", $ret);
```

I just added u behind #is and it worked.